# X-Frame Options

Tags: apache-2.2, x-frame-options

I am struggling with the X-Frame-Options. I have a HTML page and want to include (with an iframe) another HTML page. The first warning said:

> Refused to display ../map.html in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

I tried this:

```
Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"
```

as well as:

```
Header set X-FRAME-OPTIONS SAMEORIGIN
```

and this:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

But then I also get this error:

> Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('DENY, SAMEORIGIN') encountered when loading ../map.html. Falling back to 'DENY'.

I have searched trough all my files, but there is no `.htaccess` / `httpd.conf` file which contain the X-Frame Option `DENY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the default X-Frame Option 'DENY' in:

> httpd-ssl.conf

I changed the 'DENY' in 'SAMEORIGIN', this was not the solution. Finally, I comment out the whole option. Now it is working.

Answer (score -1):

1. Add below line in custom.conf

   ```
   Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
   ```
2. Bounce Apache server
3. Retest the issue.